# How do I source a zsh script from a bash script?

Tags: bash, macos, zsh

I need to extract some variables and functions from a `zsh` script into a `bash` script. Is there any way to do this? What I've tried (some are embarrassingly wrong, but covering everything):

`. /script/path.zsh` (zsh-isms exist, so it fails)

```
exec zsh
. /script/path.zsh
exec bash
```

```
zsh << 'EOF'
. /script/path.zsh
EOF
```

```
chsh -s zsh
. /script/path.zsh
chsh -s bash
```

This [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67340433/export-a-function-from-zsh-to-bash-script) is the closest I've found. Unfortunately, I have too many items to import for that to be feasible, and neither script is anywhere near a polyglot. However, the functions and variables that I need to import are polyglots.

Comment: You can't, any more than you can load a Perl library into a Python interpreter. To source a file is to _run it in your already-invoked interpreter_. If the interpreter doesn't know how to read the file, it can't possibly run it.

Comment: Now, there _are_ plenty of ways to extract variables with simple types (by having zsh source the script and then write the variables in a format bash can read), but if the functions contain zshisms, you're simply out-of-luck -- bash _can't_ run a function that's written only for zsh.

Comment: ...what workarounds, if any, exist depends on the details of those functions -- if the function is self-contained enough that it doesn't need to be able to change shell state, f/e, you can have bash start a copy of zsh that sources the file, runs a function, and exits every time it needs the function run; but if the function's invocation is supposed to change bash's state, then you need to do the work to translate those state changes, and it quickly gets into a place where it would just be easier to rewrite the script at hand.

Comment: IMO, your best approach would be to separate the "common" functions and variables into a separate file that both bash and zsh can source.

Answer (score 0):

You can "scrape" the zsh source file for what you need, then execute the code in bash using `eval`. Here's an example for doing this for a few functions:

File `script.zsh`:

```sh
test1() {
    echo "Hello from test1"
}

test2() {
    echo $((1 + $1))
}
```

File `script.sh` (bash):

```sh
# Specify source script and functions
source_filename="script.zsh"
source_functions=" \
    test1          \
    test2          \
"

# Perform "sourcing"
function_definitions="$(python -B -c "
import re
with open('${source_filename}', mode='r') as file:
    content = file.read()
for func in '${source_functions}'.split():
    print(re.search(func + r'\(\).*?\n}', content, flags=re.DOTALL).group())
" )"
eval "${function_definitions}"

# Try out test functions
test1                         # Hello from test1
n=5
echo "$n + 1 is $(test2 $n)"  # 5 + 1 is 6
```

Run the bash script and it will make use of the functions `test1` and `test2` defined in the zsh script:

```sh
bash script.sh
```

The above makes use of Python, specifically its [`re`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) module. It simply looks for character sequences of the form `funcname()`, and assumes that the function ends at the first `}`. So it's not very general, but works if you write your functions in this manner.